# .DS-store problems when trying to publish with web deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I'm trying to use web-deploy but get this when running web deploy

> Error    4   Copying file Content\font\ui-fonts\Font - Logo, headlines.DS_Store to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\font\ui-fonts\Font - Logo,
>   headlines.DS_Store failed. Could not find file
>   'Content\font\ui-fonts\Font - Logo,
>   headlines.DS_Store'.     0   0   ui.WebUI

my ms build works fine

Comment: Delete the .DS_Store files; find out how they are being created and prevent them from reappearing.

Comment: ok, but there are stacks of them boo hoo :(

Comment: `del /s /q /f /a:h .DS_STORE`

Comment: del /s /q /f /a:h .DS_STORE we will execute that command on where? and paramaters needs to explain...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

> ```
> Copying file style\.DS_Store to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\style\.DS_Store failed.
>
> Could not find file 'style\.DS_Store'.
> ```

Find and delete the .DS_STORE files that your project contains.

[image: .DS_Store]